# Generate random number not in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I want to generate a random number that is not in the array. If it is, then it will keep generating until it generates a number that is not. Then it will append that number to the array.

After the first time, it doesn't work. The first time always works since the array is empty. I think there is something wrong with my `while` loop.

Here is my code:

```
var selectQuestion: UInt32 = 0
var questionsArray:[UInt32] = []
var questionNotAsked = false

if (questionsArray.isEmpty == true) {
    questionNotAsked = true
    selectQuestion = arc4random_uniform(10)
}

while(!questionNotAsked) {
    selectQuestion = arc4random_uniform(10) //0-9
    for questions in self.questionsArray {
        if selectQuestion == questions {
            self.questionNotAsked = false
            return
        } else {
            self.questionNotAsked = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the array is empty, you add a random number and set `questionNotAsked` to `true`. After that, the loop will never be entered because `!questionNotAsked` will never be true.

Comment: Checkout the concept of recursion for generation of the numbers

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Why use recursion for this?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I fixed the questionNotAsked and replaced the return with a break.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking for numbers between 0 and 9, fill an array with those values and [shuffle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) it.  Then iterate through however many you need.  If you get to the end, re-shuffle and repeat.

Answer (score -3):

It's like an assignment. Do it and research it. It's a very useful and fun experience.

I just follow what you want to achieve. There are more elegant ways to implement this.

```
    var questionsArray:[UInt32] = []

    func nextRandom(){

    var selectQuestion: UInt32 = 0
    var questionNotAsked = false

    while(!questionNotAsked) {
        selectQuestion = arc4random_uniform(10) //0-9
        for questions in questionsArray {
            if selectQuestion == questions {
                questionNotAsked = true
                break;
            }
        }
        questionNotAsked = !questionNotAsked
        if questionNotAsked {
             questionsArray.append(selectQuestion)}
        }
    }

      nextRandom()
      nextRandom()
      nextRandom()
      nextRandom()
      nextRandom()
    nextRandom()
    nextRandom()
    nextRandom()
    nextRandom()
    nextRandom()

    print(questionsArray)
```